# Beamer frame numbering

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I was working on a beamer presentation. I want the page numbering to start from the second page (the first page is title).

But, when I used the known tweaks, the page numbering still starts from the title page, though it is hidden there. A minimal working example is given here.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace*{1mm}\hfill\insertpagenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hfill\vspace*{1mm}}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}
This is the first page of mine, but it shows 2/2.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This what I want for the given example: The second page should show 1/1 in its foot line.

Thanks in advance and waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you must replace `\insertpagenumber` with `\insertframenumber`.

To turn off the frame number for the first frame you can add `noframenumbering` as option in the start of  `frame` environment

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},11pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace*{1mm}\hfill
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hfill\vspace*{1mm}}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}}

\begin{frame}
This is the first frame of mine, it shows 1/1.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need a  second run of TEX for the account  of totalframenumber.